# How to prevent document files from being downloaded or printed

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, document-library, permissions

Let's say I have a .pdf file, and I want the user to be able to view it. But do not want them to be able to download or print the file - basically view in browser. Is there a way to do that?

I found from my search that there is a permissions option at [How do I get the document to just open instead of having to save it?](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/3373906d-3a9d-4665-ad4b-1fdb0f3d41a2/how-do-i-get-the-document-to-just-open-instead-of-having-to-save-it?forum=sharepointgeneralprevious)

But that still doesn't do exactly what I want.. Is it more of a backend code integration thing then?

Comment: Welcome to SharePoint StackExchange :) , Could you please take a quick tour at https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/tour to get informed badge! Thank you for your contribution!

Answer (score 3):

Have you ever heard about **Information Rights Management** in SharePoint?

I think `Information Rights Managemen` is what you need to use because:

- IRM helps you to control and protect files that are downloaded from lists or libraries.
- IRM enables you to limit the actions that users can take on files that have been downloaded from lists or libraries.
- IRM can also limit the rights of the users who are allowed to read files so that they cannot take actions such as print copies of the files or copy text from them.
- You can use IRM on lists or libraries to limit the dissemination of sensitive content.

> **NOTE**: If you're using SharePoint Server 2013, a server administrator must install protectors on all front-end Web servers for
>   every file type that the people in your organization want to protect
>   by using IRM.

---

For more details check

- [IRM in sharepoint 2013](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/189986/irm-in-sharepoint-2013)
- [Set up Information Rights Management (IRM) in SharePoint admin center](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Set-up-Information-Rights-Management-IRM-in-SharePoint-admin-center-239CE6EB-4E81-42DB-BF86-A01362FED65C)